# dayrender fullcalendar function don't work in my solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using JS fullcalendar.I've found this code :

```
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
           header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
       },

 defaultView: 'month',
 dayRender: function (date, cell) {
        var id = 'checkbox-2-' + (date.getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0);
        var exists = selectedDays.indexOf('checkbox-2-' + (date.getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0));
        if (exists > -1) {
            cell.append('<input id="' + id + '" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" checked/>');
        }
        else{
            cell.append('<input id="' + id + '" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>');
        }
    $('#'+id).change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {              
        selectedDays.push($(this).attr('id'));        
    }
    else{
        
        var index = selectedDays.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));            
        if (index > -1) {
            selectedDays.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
 });
   
}
});
```

But the dayrender function don't work for me and don't show the calendar grid,but only the header(Today,Next etc.).

Comment: Which version of fullCalendar are you using?

Comment: I don't know.A version with the dao part written in c# :the date of the sources is 2021/04/23.

Comment: You need to look in the fullCalendar.js file then, it usually says the version at the top. Can't really help you accurately without that info. The date the c# code was written is irrelevant

Comment: Ok,The version is v3.1.0

Comment: Thanks. As per this demo of your code: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/VwbmrPM?editable=true&editors=001 it produces a console error - did you check for that? It states that `date.getTime is not a function`...which makes sense because (as per the [fullCalendar 3 docs for dayRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dayRender)), `date` is a Moment object, and [there is no getTime function on Moment objects](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

Comment: I wonder if you got confused between momentJS objects and native JS Date objects (because there is a [getTime function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) on the latter). Since `getTime` returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, you can simply replace it with the [equivalent momentJS function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) which does the same thing

Comment: Thanks Adyson.and if I wanted to select the individual events via checkbox, as I could do. I tried ineventRender : event.append(
                    '<input id="' + id + '" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" checked/>'
             ); but don't work.

Comment: `event` is the event data object. Try appending it to `element` instead - that's the variable which contains the HTML element which will be displayed on the calendar. There's a clear explanation and example in the documentation so you can understand what each argument to the function represents. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventRender